# Attempting to re-use selector tag in a component throws error

Tags: angular

I am trying to re-use a selector in a component and I am stucked.

Here is snippets

```
<app-findit *ngIf="id === '3'
 [id]="id"></app-findit>
```

where I attempt to serve the view I get below errors

```
1. If 'app-findit' is an Angular component and it has 'id' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'app-findit' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Please what could be wrong as I am confused

Comment: Did you add `AppFinditComponent` to your `AppModule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Scenarios :

1. Are you trying to use this component on other Module (other than the on when it's declared) if yes Add it to your module:

`@NgModule({ declarations: [AppFindit],  ...  })`

2. be sure the inside your component class there is something like :

`@Input() id: string;`

if not you need one because you are trying to invoke an input with this syntax `[id]` not a selector for a selector try [Template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) will give you something like this :

```
<app-findit #myComp />
```

Comment: error NG1006: Two incompatible decorators on class
    
     16 @Component({
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

Comment: I think you have a typo share your class pleasse